# Implementing calendar view like of Mac in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

Is there any Sample code available which can help me implementing calendar day,week and month view as of Mac/iPad.
Searched a lot but couldn't find any thing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't Tapku meet your needs? It's free (even to use in commercial products) and open (you can do whatever you want with it, including design and behavior changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Tapku Library](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers). It's not exactly as of Mac/iPad calendar, but quite customizable and may meet your needs or at least become a base for your own calendar